# PHP Form Validation and Submit to Database

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I would like to ask how do I set PHP "form validation" and "submit to database" in one single php file? This is what I tried to do in PART 1 and PART 2.

```
$latErr = $lngErr = $messageErr = "";
$lat = $lng = $message = "";

$tbl_name="stickers";
$datetime=date("d-m-y H:i:s");

//PART 1 - form validation method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if (empty($_POST["inputfield1"])) {
  $latErr = "* Latitude is required. Please enable your browser geolocation settings.";
  } else {
  $lat = test_input($_POST["inputfield1"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["inputfield2"])) {
  $lngErr = "* Longitude is required. Please enable your browser geolocation settings.";
  }else{
  $lng = test_input($_POST["inputfield2"]);
  }

if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
  $messageErr = "* Please enter your message.";
  } else {
  $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

}


//PART 2 - check if all 3 parameters are filled, if yes then insert into database
if (isset($lat, $lng, $message)){

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(username, message, datetime, lat, lng )VALUES('$user-   >username','$message', '$datetime', '$lat', '$lng')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//check if query successful
if($result){
$post_info = "Your msg is successfully posted!";
}else{
$post_info = "Oops, there is an error posting the msg.";
}


mysql_close();
}

function test_input($data){
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
```

It doesn't work. It just insert blanks into the database. Something is wrong but I dunno what is it? Anyone can advice. Thanks.

Comment: Where you declare `$message`, `$user`, `$lat`, etc?

Comment: @user2192094 Where you declare `$tbl_name` and `$datetime`?

Comment: @Mr.Smith I have declared the variables ontop.

Comment: Function `test_input()`. What is its code?

Comment: @user2192094 `datetime` is `datetime` in database?

Comment: thanks @LucasHenrique. I use !empty instead of isset and it works. As advised by Alexey Palamar below. Thanks Mr Smith too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to use empty() instead of isset()?

```
//PART 1 - form validation method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if (empty($_POST["inputfield1"])) {
  $latErr = "* Latitude is required. Please enable your browser geolocation settings.";
  } else {
  $lat = test_input($_POST["inputfield1"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["inputfield2"])) {
  $lngErr = "* Longitude is required. Please enable your browser geolocation settings.";
  }else{
  $lng = test_input($_POST["inputfield2"]);
  }

if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
  $messageErr = "* Please enter your message.";
  } else {
  $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

}


//PART 2 - check if all 3 parameters are filled, if yes then insert into database
if ( !empty($lat) && !empty($lng) && !empty($message) ){

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(username, message, datetime, lat, lng )VALUES('$user-   >username','$message', '$datetime', '$lat', '$lng')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//check if query successful
if($result){
$post_info = "Your msg is successfully posted!";
}else{
$post_info = "Oops, there is an error posting the msg.";
}


}
else {
$post_info = "Empty content.";
}
mysql_close();
```